# spacebar clicker 99999999999999 clicks

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, list, list-view

All of my lists are in Quick Edit view by default and I want to change it to be the Standard View by default (see standard view image below).

I read a solution that tells me to go to **Advance Settings > Quick property editing**, and set it to "**No**."  When I do so, it still defaults to Quick Edit mode, but I can't see data and I cannot exit Quick Edit mode via the "exit quick edit" button/option.  The button just doesn't work.

Besides, I do want to quick edit option (see standard view image), I just do not want it to be in quick edit mode initially.

Where can I make this change globally?  Or even at the list settings level.

**Quick Edit View**

[image: Quick Edit View]

**Standard View**

[image]

Comment: Do you have **All items** view in your list?

Comment: If I create a new view, set it to the Standard View type, and make it the default view for the list, it solved my issue for that list.  How can I make this the default for all lists site wide?  I'm guessing having it default to quick mode is not the norm, so there must be a site level setting, no?

Comment: Yes, standard All Items view should be the default view of newly created list.

Comment: How are you creating a new list? From browser/UI or by using any code/script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make another view (probably **All items** view comes with SharePoint list when you create it) then follow below steps:

1. Go to List and from there navigate to **List Settings**.
2. From list settings page, scroll down to the Views section and click on the view name you want to make default.
3. Check the **Make this the default view** checkbox below view name on view settings page.
4. Click **OK**.

**Note**:

If you don't have any other standard view in list then you need to create a new list view on your own.

Check below official documentation to create a new view (Select **Standard View** type while creating a new view):

[Create, change, or delete a view of a list or library](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-change-or-delete-a-view-of-a-list-or-library-27ae65b8-bc5b-4949-b29b-4ee87144a9c9).

Comment: Also keep **Advance Settings > Quick property editing** set to **Yes**.

Comment: Please [Upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you.

Comment: Yes,  that fixes it at the list level, which is great.  How can I change this for all of my lists at the site level?  Is this the normal default?  All my lists are in quick edit mode when I go to them by default.

Comment: How are you creating a new list? From browser/UI or by using any code/script? Are you using any site design script or anything to create list? How it is setting quick edit mode as a default view?

Comment: I am using SharePoint 2019, editing from Browser through normal GUI. I am Adding App > Custom List.  Then I have been just setting up basic lists.  Later I realized it was defaulting in this manner.

Comment: Strange! The default view should be standards all items view.

Comment: I believe my issue is very specific to something weird on my end related to templates for lists.  I resolved it but I am not sure how.  In terms of how to change this on a per list basis my question was answered.  And so I accepted the answer above. Thank you.